# Method Global to Project (Java)

Tags: java, android

I require a method to be global to the whole Java project, but I am unsure how to proceed. I am programming for Android but this would be the case for any Java project.

I want the following method to be availible to any class in the project:

```
public int dpToPx(int dp, Context c) {

    DisplayMetrics displayMetrics = c.getResources().getDisplayMetrics();
    int px = Math.round(dp * (displayMetrics.xdpi / DisplayMetrics.DENSITY_DEFAULT));       
    return px;
}
```

My thoughts are to put it in a class of its own, but then questions arise regarding the use of constructors.  Whats the most efficient way to do this?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

A convenient way of doing this, is to make a utility class with a static method.

```
public class AppUtils {
    public static int dpToPx(int dp, Context c) {
        // your source code.
    }
}
```

The method can then be accessed anywhere, by calling `AppUtils.dpToPx()`

```
public class MyActivity extends Activity {

    @Override
    protected void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
        super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
        setContentView(R.layout.my_activity);

        int px = AppUtils.dpToPx(240, this);
    }
}
```

Answer (score 2):

Making the method **static** would be one choice.or if you want to call the method in  class1,from class2 .you should instantiate the class1 in class2 ,then only you can call that method

Answer (score 1):

I would put it in public class and make this method public and static.

This way you can call it from anywhere.

Answer (score 1):

If possible, a public static method on a class is the simplest approach.

If you need to maintain a global application state, the preferred place to do that is in an [Application](http://developer.android.com/reference/android/app/Application.html) subclass.

You can then retrieve it using `getApplication()` or `getApplicationContext()` as appropriate.

Answer (score 1):

Since the method has to available to an entire project , I suggest you `create a class that is public and put the method inside it`. I'm not so sure as to waht you mean by the problem of constructors.

Also, as an added tip, you can `package the java file as a jar` and can use it in different projects too.

Hope it helps. :)